# "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.pin | LineNumber: 7 | BytePositionInLine: 20."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating an ASP.NET Web API and I'm using Swagger UI. When I try to post data like register user, I get the following error:

```
response status 400
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-2eab5ca50f25670cbaae859bf26f0968-6647b29cdb08df1a-00",
  "errors": {
    "userRegister": [
      "The userRegister field is required."
    ],
    "$.pin": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.pin | LineNumber: 7 | BytePositionInLine: 20."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to post:

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "firstname": "test",
  "lastname": "test",
  "phone": 511223170,
  "accountType": 1,
  "iban": "GE05258155379184328548",
  "pin": 12345678901,
  "password": "qazwsxplmokn"
}
```

When I don't change anything in that values and leave them as "string" or for integer 0 it works

This is the request code:

```
    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public IActionResult Register(UserRegister userRegister)
    {
        if(_db.GetAll<string>($"select Email from dbo.Users where Email = '{userRegister.Email}'").Count() == 0)
        {
            if (_db.GetAll<string>($"select Phone from dbo.Users where Phone = {userRegister.Phone}").Count() == 0)
            {
                byte[] passwordSalt = new byte[128 / 8];
                using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
                {
                    rng.GetNonZeroBytes(passwordSalt);
                }

                string PasswordSaltWithKey = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:PasswordKey") +
                   Convert.ToBase64String(passwordSalt);

                byte[] passwordHash = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                    password: userRegister.Password,
                    salt: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordSaltWithKey),
                    prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
                    iterationCount: 100000,
                    numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
                );

                string addAuthSql = $@"
                    INSERT INTO dbo.Auth (
                        [Email],
                        [Phone],
                        [PasswordHash],
                        [PasswordSalt]
                    )VALUES(
                        '{userRegister.Email}',
                        {userRegister.Phone},
                        @PasswordHash,
                        @PasswordSalt)
```

";

```
                string addUserSql = $@"
                    INSERT INTO dbo.Users(
                        [Email],
                        [Firstname],
                        [Lastname],
                        [Phone],
                        [AccountType],
                        [IBAN],
                        [PIN]
                    )VALUES(
                        '{userRegister.Email}',
                        '{userRegister.Firstname}',
                        '{userRegister.Lastname}',
                        {userRegister.Phone},
                        {userRegister.AccountType},
                        '{userRegister.IBAN}',
                        {userRegister.PIN}
                    )
                    ";

                List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();


                SqlParameter passwordSaltParameter = new SqlParameter("@PasswordSalt", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                passwordSaltParameter.Value = passwordSalt;

                SqlParameter passwordHashParameter = new SqlParameter("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                passwordHashParameter.Value = passwordHash;

                sqlParameters.Add(passwordSaltParameter);
                sqlParameters.Add(passwordHashParameter);

                if (_db.ExecuteWithParameters(addAuthSql, sqlParameters) && _db.Execute(addUserSql))
                {
                    return Ok("Succesfully added user");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("ERROR");
                }
            }
            return BadRequest($"PHONE_{userRegister.Phone}_ALREADY_EXISTS");
        }
        return BadRequest($"EMAIL_{userRegister.Email}_ALREADY_EXISTS");
    }
```

The model:

```
namespace Api.Models
{
    public class UserRegister
    {
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? Firstname { get; set; }
        public string? Lastname { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int AccountType { get; set; }
        public string? IBAN { get; set; }
        public int PIN { get; set; }
        public string?  Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I thought it was because of namings and I tried to add `[JsonPropertyName]` but it still didn't work. I couldn't find anything in Google that helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your pin value, which is 12345678901, is higher than the max value an `int` can hold which is 2147483647. Either change the type of your pin to a string (if your logic dictates it can hold both letters, numbers, special characters), add a max value validation ex:9999, or change the type to a `long`.

P.S: Don't put all of your logic into the controller, separate it into logical modules (service, repository, validators etc.)